# Ef to MySql creates an extra column

Tags: mysql, database, entity-framework, database-schema

I'm creating a MySql db with the code first approach:

```
    public partial class Client
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            //relational properties
            public ICollection<RNC> RNCs { get; set; }

            public Client()
            {
                this.RNCs = new HashSet<RNC>();
            }
        }

        public partial class RNC
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            //relational properties
            public int Client_ID { get; set; }

            public RNC()
            {
                this.NodeBs = new HashSet<NodeB>();
            }        
        }

public class ClientMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Client>
    {
        public ClientMap()
        {
            HasRequired(x => x.Name);
        }
    }

    public class RNCMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<RNC>
    {
        public RNCMap()
        {
            HasRequired(x => x.Name);
            HasRequired(x => x.Client).WithMany(x => x.RNCs).HasForeignKey(x => x.Client_ID);            
        }
    }
```

When looking at the db there is a Client_ID and Client_ID1 in the database. Why and how do I remove that and set it to be a FK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate `Client_ID` because the first `Client_ID` is not a Foreign Key, it just a normal column.
The second `Client_ID1` is because EF convention finds 
`public ICollection<RNC> RNCs { get; set; }` on RNC,
but fail to also find the reference, in this case `public Client Client { get;set; }`

The solution is either removing the `Client_ID` property OR (also adding the navigation reference + specifying the foreign key attribute).

```
public partial class RNC
{
    //relational properties
    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public int Client_ID { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks you made me realize I didn't include my configurations in the `DB_Context`